# Are there multiple control quantum gates where the control bit is an OR relationship?

Tags: qiskit

In general, the control bits of a multi-control bit quantum gate are in an AND relationship. Is there a quantum gate that makes the control bits an OR relationship?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can implement standard AND-controlled $U^\dagger$ gate you can implement your OR-controlled $U$ gate without any additional controls, as follows

[image]

This is an example for the $S$ gate and 2 control qubits, but it applies universally. A `qiskit` code snippet for checking.

```
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit
from qiskit.circuit.library import SGate
from qiskit.quantum_info import Operator
import numpy as np

qc = QuantumCircuit(3)
qc.x(0)
qc.x(1)
qc.s(2)
qc.append(SGate().control(2).inverse(), [0, 1, 2])
qc.x(0)
qc.x(1)

u_target = np.kron(np.diag([1, 0, 0, 0]), np.identity(2))+np.kron(np.diag([0, 1, 1, 1]), np.array([[1, 0], [0, 1j]]))
u_qs = Operator(qc.reverse_bits()).data

print(np.allclose(u_target, u_qs))
qc.draw(output='mpl')
```

Comment: Great, looks like it saves qubits more than the first option.

Comment: @R-XZhao 'saving qubits' might have multiple meanings, such as gate count, gate depth or something else. It's better to say precisely what are you optimizing for.

Comment: I'm building a PQC where one of the submodules wants to implement multiple control quantum gates, and the control relationship is OR or XOR. I can design it by referring to the QISKIT official guide, but it uses a large number of auxiliary qubits, which is a challenge in the nearly 29 qubits system.

Comment: So my idea is to use as few auxiliary qubits as possible without changing the number of qubits, otherwise it will become difficult to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the fact that:
$$a \lor b = \neg(\neg a \land \neg b)$$
For example, in the following circuit the unitary is applied if either $q_0$ or $q_1$ (or both) equals $1$:

[image]

Comment: This seems to be no longer a gate, but a network. I don't know if there is a quantum gate with OR relationship in quantum information. It can be optical or superconducting. At present, the network is very bloated because of the single relationship of control bits.

Comment: May I ask if it is possible to design a quantum circuit in which the control bits are in an XOR relationship, hoping to save qubits as much as possible.